# ios listview index of row seems to be off

Tags: ios

I am using a listview that has a thumbnail image in it. I am also using a webservice to retrieve all info.

in my cellForRowAtIndexPath method I call the service to retrieve the record and then check to see if it has an image attached to it. This is just a bool. Then if it does I call the service again, using a different method, to get the thumbnail. All of the logic seems to be in place and in the right order but the images are shown in the wrong cells and also duplicated.

When I step through the code to debug, it seems to fire the service call for each cell and rather than jumping right to the response action it goes to the next row/cell. once all rows are populated then it goes to the response. Is this normal for the debugger? Maybe the calls to the service are asynchronous and that is why? There is a soap "library" included but it doesnt seem to be named anywhere and it doesnt seem to be doing an async request, which would be dumb for this application. I inherited this project from a 3rd party dev.

Also I am a .net dev and am used to the visual studio debugger so maybe that is causing some issues.

sorry if my terms arent correct as I am fairly new to ios and obj-c.

Code:
Service call to get image:

```
[service GetPictureThumbnail:self action:@selector(GetThumbResponse:) clientid: [AppDelegate clientID] commid:[UserSettings getInstance].selectedID mod:@"CCR" pkey:_ccr.l maxWidth:94 maxHeight:98];
```

GetThumbResponse:

```
// Handle errors
if([value isKindOfClass:[NSError class]]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", value);
}

// Handle faults
if([value isKindOfClass:[SoapFault class]]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", value);
}


// Do something with the NSString* result
Picture_Object* result = (Picture_Object*)value;
NSLog(@"%@", result);
[_cell.imgThumb setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:result.e]];
```

all other data in the cells are fine but the image is the only thing that would not be included in the initial call to the service.

Thanks.

Comment: What is `_cell`? And what error logs / exceptions do you see?

Comment: Are you trying to use debugger while in process, try put NSLog like download started, step2, step3, step4 etc.. and see what happens in normal mode, without debugger..

Comment: _cell is the cell that goes in the listview. I need to declare it so that I can use it later to set the thumbnail in the getThumbResponse action

Comment: The question is where is _cell declared? Is it an instance variable? if so, of what object? The short answer to your question is that the call to download the image is probably async, as well it should be on a mobile device, and so as the pictures come back you need to look up the correct cell for that item and populate the image.

Comment: no it is in the .h. how would I look them up? maybe pass that info to the getThumbResponse method? Why would it be duplicating also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my experience, it is not good to do processing in cellForRowAtIndexPath:.

Everytime you scroll up and down, your cells will refresh and call that method over and over again, causing weird inconsistencies. The best way to populate cells (again, based on my experience, which may not coincide with everyones) is to prepare arrays in your own methods which hold the data to be displayed in the cells. So then when you call cellForRow: , you just get the data similar to something below.

```
[imageArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
```

that way when you scroll up and down, you're merely picking data out of your arrays, and displaying them in the cell, instead of constantly doing network requests.

I've had all sorts of trouble with this, until I started processing my data outside of that method. Wish I knew earlier, would have saved me lots of grief.

This may not be a direct answer to your question, but it is a better way to approach tableViews (especially when your cells/tableViews start getting complicated).

*edit: be sure to call the line below after the network request, and processing of data into arrays.

```
[_tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: This seems like a good idea. I was toying with this as it seems that the soap library included in this project makes it very difficult to pass any additional variables in the action. Also, the async nature of the communication makes it hard to assign the image back to the appropriate cell.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by difficulty passing additional variables into action.But for the async nature, have a look at the edit I made in my answer.